# Can all recursive structures be replaced by a non recursive solution?

Tags: haskell, data-structures, f#

For example, could you define a list in Haskell without defining a recursive structure? Or replace all lists by some function(s)?

```
data List a = Empty | (a, List a) -- <- recursive definition
```

**EDIT**

I gave the list as an example, but I was really asking about all data structures in general.
Maybe we only need one recursive data structure for all cases where recursion is needed? Like the Y combinator being the only recursive function needed. @TikhonJelvis 's answer made me think about that.
Now I'm pretty sure this post is better suited for cs.stackexchange.

**About current selected answer**

I was really looking for answers that looked more like the ones given by @DavidYoung & @TikhonJelvis, but they only give a partial answer and I appreciate them.
So, if any has an answer that uses functional concepts, please share.

Comment: are you hinting at [recursion schemes](http://patrickthomson.ghost.io/an-introduction-to-recursion-schemes/) or something?

Comment: @CarstenKönig I have only read the title of that paper, I had no idea it could be the answer to this question, but it would make sense, since I'm indeed trying to restructure an App to be more reactive using f# and reactive extensions. Let me check it out. Thanks a lot.

Comment: well the thing is there will be some recursive definition finally and it kind of depends on what you see as the defining property of a list - for example you could equate a list with a `fold`ing-operation and it will have no recursion in it's data-structure (it will just be a function) but it will most likely have it in it's evaluation - or you could see it as a big array with a length, or ...

Comment: @CarstenKönig Yeah, we all want the execution to appear recursive, but not the data structures that we use, is that what you tried to say?

Comment: no - the question is just hard to answer if you don't say exactly what a list should be

Comment: I'm reading the paper, perhaps I meant "call-tree" instead of "execution". Or I might be trying to hard to connect the ideas, I'll keep reading.

Comment: If your currently not 100% sure what your actual question is, it might be a better idea to close (not delete) this question for a while. It could reopened later.

Comment: @Zeta, I'm sure about my question, the answer could be as simple as yes or no. What I'm not sure is if the paper answers it.

Comment: @LayGonzález it does not - I was just wondering if your question was in that direction - but as I said your question is really hard to answer (I can think of several ways to cheat my way out if you don't give the exact properties you want a list to have - for example in F# it will never be infinite so I could define a list to be a record of a really big array and a contained elements (length) parameter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this question breaks down into considering three distinct feature subsets that Haskell provides:

1. Facilities for defining new data types.
2. A repertoire of built-in types.
3. A foreign function interface that allows interfacing with functionality external to the language.

Looking only at (1), the native type definition facilities don't really provide for defining any infinitely-large types other than by recursion.

Looking at (2), however, [Haskell 2010 provides the `Data.Array` module](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch14.html), which provides array types that together with (1) can be used to build non-recursive definitions of many different structures.

And even if the language did not provide arrays, (3) means that we could bolt them to the language as an FFI extension.  Haskell implementations are also allowed to provide extra functionality that can be used for this in stead of the FFI, and many libraries for GHC exploit those (e.g., [`vector`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector)).

So I'd say that the best answer is that Haskell only allows you to define nonrecursive collection types only to the extent that it provides you with basic built-in ones that you can use as building blocks for more complex ones.

Comment: Perhaps the least exciting answer, but is simple and true. Arrays, loops, gotos, int and floats are enough for everything. Recursive data types can me replaced by other solution, which may not even be data types. So, if you can model an assembly or c interpreter in haskell, then that would be one solution.

Answer (score 6):

That's a bit of an odd question. I think the answer is *not really*, but the definition of the data type does not have to be recursive directly.

Ultimately, lists are recursive data structures. You can't define them without having some sort of recursion *somewhere*. It's core to their essence.

However, we don't have to make the actual definition of `List` recursive. Instead, we can factor out recursion into a single data type `Fix` and then define all other recursive types with it. In a sense, `Fix` just captures the essence of what it means for a data structure to be recursive. (It's the type-level version of the `fix` function, which does the same thing for functions.)

```
data Fix f = Roll (f (Fix f))
```

The idea is that `Fix f` corresponds to `f` applied to itself repeatedly. To make it work with Haskell's algebraic data types, we have to throw in a `Roll` constructor at every level, but this does not change what the type represents.

Essentially, `f` applied to itself repeatedly like this is the essence of recursion.

Now we can define a non-recursive analog to `List` that takes an extra type argument `f` that replaces our earlier recursion:

```
data ListF a f = Empty | Cons a f
```

This is a straightforward data type that is *not* recursive.

If we combine the two, we get our old `List` type except with some extra `Roll` constructors at each recursive step.

```
type List a = Fix (ListF a)
```

A value of this type looks like this:

```
Roll (Cons 1 (Roll (Cons 2 (Roll Empty))))
```

It carries the same information as `(Cons 1 (Cons 2 Empty))` or even just `[1, 2]`, but a few extra constructors sprinkled through.

So if you were given `Fix`, you could define `List` without using recursion. But this isn't particularly special because, in a sense, `Fix` *is* recursion.

Comment: Now I'm wondering if there's a version of `Fix` for functions of kinds other than `*->*`.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure if *all* recursive structures can be replaced by a non-recursive version but some certainly can, including lists. One possible way to do this is with what is called a *[Boehm-Berarducci encoding](http://www.haskellforall.com/2014/09/morte-intermediate-language-for-super.html#recursion)*. This a way to represent a structure as a function, specifically the fold over that structure (`foldr` in the case of a list):

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

type List a = forall x . (a -> x -> x) -> x -> x
                      -- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^    ^
                      -- Cons branch      Nil branch
```

(From the above link with slightly different formatting)

This type is also something like a case analysis over the list. The first argument represents the cons case and the second argument represents the nil case.

In general, the branches of a sum type become different arguments to the function and fields of a product type become function types with an argument for each field. Note that in the encoding above, the nil branch is (in general) a non-function because the nil constructor takes no arguments, while the cons branch has two arguments since the cons constructor takes two arguments. The recursion parts of the definition are "replaced" with a Rank N type (called `x` here).

Comment: The above encoding is general enough to cover the vast majority of recursive definitions. Maybe something which is not covered is polymorphic recursion, e.g. `data A a = Empty | Branch a (A (a,a))` -- note that `A a` is not defined in terms of `A a` but of `A (a,a)`. So it's `A` which is defined in terms of itself, not `A a`.

Comment: @chi That's a good point. I wonder if there *is* a function type encoding that would work for that kind of non-regular data type...